# How model a 1D CNN + LSTM network where each time-step is a set of 1D arrays?

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm trying to model a Keras-based network using a set of 1D CNN and LSTM layers. Most of the available examples on the web uses data in the shape such as `(1, 30, 50)` (1 sample containing 30 time-steps with 50 features each).

However, each time step in my dataset is composed of a number of 1D arrays. A 10 time-step sample would be `(1, 10, 100, 384)` (1 batch - a single sample, 10 time-steps each containing 100 arrays with 384 features). So, how should I define a model with such shape?

I really could have flatten each time-step data `(100*384)`, but that seems quite inadequate, as could void all the CNN processing... Plus, each time-step data is really 1D: **it is not spacial data**.

I have already defined a simple model such as below, but i think it's using the `batch_size` of the input shape incorrectly. I think its trying to learn from "482 samples" and not from a single sample with "482 time-steps"...

```py
data_input_shape = (482, 100, 384)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(300, 1, activation="relu", input_shape=(100,384)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Conv1D(256, 1, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 1, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(5))

model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right that the current model learns from 482 samples each with 100 time steps and 384 features which seems not to be what you want. Do the 100 arrays have anything in common? Like, is feature 0 of array 0 of the same type of feature 0 of array 1?

Comment: @SaTa: Those are local features extracted directly from input images. So, each image is represented by 100 vectors with 384 values each one. The aim of the temporal CNN is to grasp some sort of relationship among such data, coupled with a RNN, as each image are closely related to the N previous images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the following two case as you have already mentioned that the 100 arrays are not spatially correlated:

1. The 384 values of each feature are spatially independent.
2. The 384 values of each feature are spatially dependent. For example, they are values across a frequency range after some FFT or similar operation.

In case 1, you have basically 100x384 independent feature. So flatting seems to be the option to go with.

In case 2 though, it might make sense to apply a 2D convolution across the features. Here is how:

First, you should prepare your data in the right format. Assuming that your data has 482 time steps, you should decide how many time steps you like to have in each sample. For example, you can decide to have 10 time steps in each sample, which with no overlapping between the samples will give you about 48 samples. So the data now would be of shape (48, 10, 100, 384). In addition, we should add an additional dimension as channel to be able to apply a 2D convolution in Keras. So your data would become of shape (48, 10, 100, 384, 1)

Next, you can decide on the architecture. We will apply a Conv2D to each array at each time step. We use a kernel size of (1, x) or (100, x) since your arrays are not spatially related. Here is an example architecture:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (1, 5), activation="relu"), input_shape=(10, 100, 384, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((1, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (100, 9), activation="relu"), input_shape=(10, 100, 384, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((1, 4))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

A few additional notes:

- You can certainly add more layers of each type.
- TimeDistruted is new above. You can read about it [here](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/).
- If you have images to begin with, consider using CNN/LSTM hybrid or Conv3D from the beginning vs extracting 100 arrays from the image.
- Take a look at ConvLSTM2D [here](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) for combined CNN and LSTM layer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This should help to develop a better model to solve my problem...